# Avoid SQL INSERT duplicates for column value based on another column value

Tags: php, mysql, insert, duplicates

Not sure if the question is quite clear so any recommendations are welcome.

I have following table:

```
Table1
----------
ID   fk_soc   fk_product   value
1    365      20           654896
2    365      21           654897
3    365      25           654898
4    820      20           114352
5    820      21           114381
6    820      25           114382
```

As you can see, in the second column, I can have same `fk_product` number set for different customer ID. But how can I avoid duplicate record for `fk_product` for same customer? I.e. avoid

```
Table1
----------
ID   fk_soc   fk_product   value
1    365      20           654896
2    365      20           whatever_here
```

If I set `fk_product` as unique, I won't be able to insert record for another customer. Records are inserted with normal SQL INSERT INTO and come from an HTML form:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (fk_soc, fk_distributor_product_code, fk_product)
VALUES (
    ' . $this->db->escape($this->fk_line) . ',
    ' . $this->db->escape($this->value) . ',
    ' . $this->db->escape($this->fk_product) . '
)
```

I've tried using:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (fk_soc, fk_distributor_product_code, fk_product)
VALUES (
    ' . $this->db->escape($this->fk_line) . ',
    ' . $this->db->escape($this->value) . ',
    ' . $this->db->escape($this->fk_product) . '
)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT ' . $this->db->escape($this->fk_product) . '
        FROM table WHERE fk_soc= ' . $this->db->escape($this->fk_soc) . '
```

but this way no record is inserted

Comment: Create unique composite index by these 2 columns. `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx ON table1 (fk_soc, fk_product);`